# Which Nuget package for IdentityServer in Asp.Net Core Web API?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have two web applications that need functionality for Authentication And Authorization.  The server side runs Asp.NET Core 3.0, client side runs Angular and I intend to implement IdentityServer with a Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE) flow.  Official IdentityServer documentation (https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io) refers to package `IdentityServer4` while the dotnet templates (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.0) use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer` .  I can't find a proper description of the latter package, it is listed as an implementation of IdentityServer.  However the configuration methods available between the two packages is different.

I would like to run IdentityServer as middleware in my web application, and issue the PKCE secret doing the authentication and authorization in full.  I am not sure if `IdentityServer4` can run as middleware in my main application or needs to be middleware in its own application, and am not sure if `Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer` supports PKCE flow.

Which package meets both my requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a discussion on the features of the Microsoft maintained nuget, and it references in April that it ***only supports an implicit flow***.  At a later stage it will support a PKCE secret flow.

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5833

The `IdentityServer4` (or specifically `IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation` for issuing the PKCE secret) can be middleware of my main application.

So I will stick to `IdentityServer4` as it meets both my requirements.